# jquery datepicker disable and also custom css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i would like have a certain dates in my jquery to be disabled or perhaps unclickable but with a different class. So far what i got is this which only disables the date but i can't seem to add a class to it.

```
var unavailableDates = ["9-7-2016"];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

var dateToday = new Date(); 

    $("#iDate").multiDatesPicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        minDate: dateToday
    });
```

I found this while doing some searching which is very close to what i want
http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pjJGf/

but i don't know how to make it so that it calls the dates instead of fixed day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function must return an array with two elements (an an optional third). The second array element is the name of the class you want to return for a day. So modify the return statement in the else part of your if condition to `return [false, "name-of-css-class", "Unavailable"];`